# ActionScript 3 Can't move movieclip to back

Tags: actionscript-3, class, this, stage

This is my code:

Main.as

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public static var bg_width = 980;
    public static var bg_height = 541;

    public function Main() 
    {
        trace("Main spawned")
        this.width = bg_width;
        this.height = bg_height;
        stage.setChildIndex(this, 0)

    }
}   
}
```

Main timeline:

```
var image = new Main();
stage.addChild(image)
```

My problem is to move the background image to the back of the stage. As for now it spawns in front of other movie clips I'd like to be visible.

I've tried both

```
this.parent.setChildIndex(this, 0)
```

And the one i last tried, in the code:

```
stage.setChildIndex(this, 0)
```

None of them are working.
This is my error message:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main()
    at _3_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Anyone know a solution? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just get rid of the `stage.setChildIndex(this, 0)` and add image like this?

```
var image = new Main();
stage.addChildAt(image, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked.

Though, my background is expected to contain movieclips that I add to it later in the code.
Previously I've used the Flash editor to design my stage, but I've read that the best way is to use classes and add instances manually through them.

Somehow the coordinates of movieclips added to the background are different from what they were, as a result of using this method to design the stage. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Yup, agree with class approach.
About coordinates it's hard to say without seeing .fla file but my guess would be Registration Point for those MovieClips.